# Resize image in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, image-resizing

Is it somehow possible to **change the height and width of an image to be equal to an arbitrary value in another cell**?

I have found  possibility to edit the position and offset values only in the API, and the getImage() function does not work in sheets.

Comment: Use `setOption` to set the width and height. Read the Chart documentation:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setOption(String,Object) Getting the values from the cells is easy and straightforward via the `SpreadsheetApp` class

Comment: I can set with `setOption` the width and height of a chart, I just do not know, how to apply it to an image. I couldn't find out how to reference to an image file. Also the following chart sizing works, but how to implement it on images?

`var chart = sheet.newChart();
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.)
  .addRange(dataRange)
  .setPosition(5, 1, 0, 0)
  .setOption('width', 100)
  .setOption('height', 100)
  
  .build();
 
  sheet.insertChart(chart);`

Comment: Oops I misread your question (somehow). In the native `SpreadsheetApp` there is no method to control the image parameters after you have inserted it. You will have to activate the Advanced Service and use the Sheets REST API to manipulate the embedded object, i.e. through use of https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#EmbeddedObjectPosition and other methods.